# Libraries for ADO.NET to rapidly bulk insert data into a database from a .csv file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services

I'd like to know if you can recommend any advanced ADO.NET libraries for working with databases.

I've discovered that LINQ-to-Entities is great for pulling data out of databases, but not at all useful for inserting data into databases. Its missing functionality like fast bulk insert, culling of duplicates, and most of the advanced functionality you can achieve with pure SQL.

So: can you recommend some ADO.NET libraries that offer the sorts of advanced functionality that LINQ-to-Entities is missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ADO.net **SqlBulkCopy** class enables quick, mass upload of records into a table:

```
    DataTable dt = s_EmptyUploadTable.Copy();
    foreach (var itm in yourList) {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Field1"] = itm.Field1;
        row["Field2"] = itm.Field2;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)) {
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn)) {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourActualSQLServerTableName";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I had the same answer, you beat me by 30 sec :) Here is the reference for SqlBulkCopy btw http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: where's the csv part of the question answered?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ Entity Data Reader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) to write an IEnumerable list to a database using SQL Bulk Copy behind the scenes. You can use this library to bulk upload the results of a LINQ query straight into the database, because the results of a LINQ query are IEnumerable.

As there are LINQ-to-everything adapters, you can do tricks like use the [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx) to grab the data out of a .csv file using a LINQ query, then the [LINQ Entity Data Reader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) to bulk write this data directly into the database.

**Case study:**

Problem: read a .csv file quickly into a database. The connection to the SQL database is via LINQ-to-Entitys from C#.

**Solution 1:** Use [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx), construct a LINQ query to pull out the data you want, then write it in using the standard LINQ-to-Entity calls (ctx.AddObject(), ctx.SaveChanges(), etc). Time taken: **30 seconds** for 20,000 records, as LINQ ends up generating a query for every single record (slooooow!!!!!).

**Solution 2:** Use [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx), construct a LINQ query to pull out the data you want into an IEnumerable, use [LINQ Entity Data Reader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) to bulk write this data directly into the target data table. Time taken: **3 seconds** for 20,000 records.

**Solution 3:** Use a a stored procedure with SQL "bulk copy". Time taken: **2 seconds** for 20,000 records. However, this solution is quite brittle as it relies on a stored procedure, and SQL bulk copy is just not compatible with some .csv file formats. This method also requires that you use a staging table between the actual target table and the .csv file, to deal with file formatting issues and to help with normalization.

And, here is the source code for solution #2:

```
static void WriteCSVtoSQLtable()
{
  // Step 1: Read .csv file into IEnumerable using LINQ-to-CSV class.

  // This section requires "LINQtoCSV" class as described at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.asp

  string inputFilePath = @"T:\x.csv";

  CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
  {
    SeparatorChar = ',',
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
  };

  IEnumerable<MyCustomColumnMappingClass> csvChains = cc.Read<MyCustomColumnMappingClass>(inputFilePath, inputFileDescription);

  // Step 2: Now write into the target table on SQL Server.

  // This section requires "EntityDataReader" class described at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader.
  public static string dbSqlConnectionString = @";Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=PhiEngine;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

  SqlConnection dbSql(dbSqlConnectionString);

  using (var tran = dbSql.BeginTransaction())
  {

    var csvFile = from p in csvChains
                select p;

    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(dbSql,
      SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints |
      SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
      SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, tran)
                     {
                       BatchSize = 1000,
                       DestinationTableName = "TStagingTable" // Temporary staging table in database.
                     };

    bc.WriteToServer(csvFile.AsDataReader()); // Extension method .AsDataReader depends on adding the EntityDataReader class to your C# project (see above).

    tran.Commit();
  }
}

// This class is used by LINQ to CSV to query the .csv file, see "LINQtoCSV" website.
public class MyCustomColumnMappingClass
{
  [CsvColumn(Name = "symbol", FieldIndex = 1)]
  public string Symbol { get; set; }

  [CsvColumn(Name = "date", FieldIndex = 3, OutputFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Has EntityDataReader been updated / nuget'ted at all?  I can only find a 2009 copy?