# c# code performance importing and analyzing csv files

Tags: c#, performance, csv, import, import-from-excel

I am importing large excel files into a SQL through a web application, each column in each row gets converted into a business object and each property for the object.

Since the fie is a csv I am performing a lot of validation in code such as checking property values against database values , if statements, case switches etc...and this is causing a large cpu load when the function is processing.

what would be a better way of processing this data?

Comment: How about using ADO.net to connect to the excel file and using an ORM of some sort?

Comment: Have you run the code under a profiler to see what is slow?

Comment: I have a same problem as yours with my pos-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider uploading the data to staging tables [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052958/libraries-for-ado-net-to-rapidly-bulk-insert-data-into-a-database-from-a-csv-fil/5052983#5052983) and performing the validation using set logic rather than row logic.  This avoids having to parse into objects at all and should both shift the CPU overhead to a different server (if your application server is underpowered) and reduce the CPU strain required.

Comment: do you have links or example for validation using set logic?

Comment: I guess Tahbaza is suggesting you to do a sql bulkcopy into a temporary table and do your validations (or part of your validations) using sql statements where you can attack a "set" of rows rather than looping row by row.