# Encapsulating Data Access logic

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I have recently purchased the DoFactory framework in an attempt to learn more about design patterns.  The product is good but it concentrates on transactional operations only e.g. a user updating a customer record or inserting a customer record.

I have an app that has scheduled tasks e.g. one thousand customers are created overnight via a web service.  I am trying to understand the best way to approach this:

Option 1

```
public sub shared InsertCustomerBatch(ByVal list as list(as Customer))  
    For Each Customer In Customers
        'Connect to database
        'Insert Customer
    Next
end public
```

Option 2

```
Public Sub InsertCustomer(ByVal list as list(as typeCustomer))
    For Each typeCustomer as typeCustomer In list
        Customer.Insert(typeCustomer)
    End For
End Public
```

Both options will obviously work, however I believe that option 2 is "better" because it follows design principles i.e. Customer.Insert is encapsulated in the Customer class.

However, after talking to a more senior developer earlier he said choose option 1, but I do not understand why.  Is option 1 "better".

Comment: Option 1 does not make much sense even if connections are pooled. Option 2 sounds good but you have to commit every N rows. How to specify N? I guess you got to try...May be 400 is good?

Comment: @Emmad Kareem, thanks. There is one sql statement per iteration so i wasn't planning to use transactions. I think you are on the right track. Can you post an answer so i can give credit? Plus 1.

Comment: The main difference, as I see it, is that in option 1, you have a clean separation between your DTO layer and your data-access layer, and in option 1 the data access objects are stateless.  In option 2, the data and the logic are melded into one state-ful class.  It can be more work, but I prefer option 1 because it will work in all of the same situations as option 2, plus some.  There will be some situations where option 2 will not work easily.

Comment: To put it another way, if you followed option 1, you could easily create wrapper classes that make them state-ful, like in option 2.  But, if your core classes were designed following option 2, it would be much more difficult to wrap them in a stateless layer, like option 1, without re-writing them.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, could you provide an example as I actually disagree with you this time (you have posted some good answers for me that I agree with in the past).

Comment: One simple example would n-tiers.  When you are separating your application into separate tiers (e.g. a web service back-end), it can become very difficult if your logic classes are not stateless.  When a request to perform a particular operation comes in through the communication layer, you want to be able to take the parameters (DTO) and pass them to a state-less logic object which will perform the operation and then return the result (DTO).  You don't want to have to first establish some kind of state in the logic object before you can perform the operation, and then throw the state away.

Comment: Option 2 can also lead to the proverbial spaghetti code.  With a separation between DTO and logic, you can divide your logic into any number of different classes.  If you put the logic into the same class as the data, then you will be tempted to put *ALL* the logic related to that entity in that same class.  As the complexity expands, so does the code in the class.  It can tend to become unwieldy.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, I have modified option 2.  Does it make more sense now to you?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure what you meant by that change.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, I have changed option 2 so that the state of the customer (typeCustomer) is passed as a parameter to Customer.Insert.  Customer.Insert then contains the SQL logic.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Don't know how I missed that.  Yes, that certainly alleviates my concern over option 2.  However, now I don't really know what you're asking.  What's the difference between options 1 and 2 that you were concerned about?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, thanks. I believe that option two is better because the data access logic is encapsulated in its own class. Do you agree? I see the option one approach all the time.

Comment: It's hard to tell, from such a simplistic example, but yes, in principle, you want the data-access logic to be in separate classes from the business layer logic, and it's nice to logically group all of the data-access logic methods into separate classes that are specific to their purpose.  For instance, I'd expect all of the methods for reading, writing, and deleting customer data to be in a `CustomerDataAccess` class and then all of the methods for working with product data to be in a `ProductDataAccess` class.  I wouldn't want them mixed with each other or with business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think one has to justify why a connection has to be opened and closed with every row in a batch scenario (option 1). One advantage may be implicit commit. However, frequent commits are not usually required in batch processing of many LOB applications. A business decision may have to be taken to determine the sensitivity of the data of course. However, it makes sense to commit rows in groups of reasonable sizes (bound by db log size).

One way is to divide a large batch size into several small logical batches and commit each batch separately. Another way is to use bulk copy to insert rows in the db when appropriate (see for example: [bulk insert data into db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052958/libraries-for-ado-net-to-rapidly-bulk-insert-data-into-a-database-from-a-csv-fi). Also note that by default, constraints on the table are not checked for the bulk copy operation unless CHECK_CONSTRAINTS is specified.

Also, it may be good to check the connection timeout setting in case it may have an effect on long transaction processing(not sure on that one). However, I guess in your case the defaults should work fine.

In conclusion, I would suggest you go with option 2, possibly with some modifications as suggested if your case calls for large number of rows.