# Faster C# ADO.NET code to insert blobs into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, blob

I'm trying to insert 1,000,000 - 20K blobs into SQL Server as fast as possible using a C# program as a proof of concept.  The code below is what I currently use but I think there should be a faster method.  I cannot use BULK LOAD APIs due to concurrency problems.  Does anyone know a faster way to accomplish this functionality?

```
private static void InsertWaveform(int batchSize = 1000, int numberOfBatches = 1000)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sampleCount = 10000;
    string typeName = @"My Old Type Name"; // varchar(50)
    short typeID = (short)rand.Next(short.MaxValue); // smallint
    string sampleBytes = new string('X', sampleCount * 2);
    byte[] samples = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sampleBytes); // varbinary(MAX)
    bool compressed = false; // bit
    int topicSessionID = rand.Next(int.MaxValue); // int
    DateTime startTimeUTC = DateTime.Now; // datetime2(7)
    DateTime endTimeUTC = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1); // datetime2(7)
    DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now; // datetime2(7)
    int totalRowsInTable;

    string queryString = @"
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Waveform] (
    [SampleCount]
    ,[TypeName]
    ,[TypeID]
    ,[Samples]
    ,[Compressed]
    ,[TopicSessionID]
    ,[StartTimeUTC]
    ,[EndTimeUTC]
    ,[CreateDate]
    ) VALUES (
    @SampleCount,
    @TypeName,
    @TypeID,
    @Samples,
    @Compressed,
    @TopicSessionID,
    @StartTimeUTC,
    @EndTimeUTC,
    @CreateDate
    );";

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime endTime;

    // Create and open the connection in a using block. This
    // ensures that all resources will be closed and disposed
    // when the code exits.
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleCount", sampleCount);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeName", typeName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", typeID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Samples", samples);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Compressed", compressed);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicSessionID", topicSessionID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTimeUTC", startTimeUTC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTimeUTC", endTimeUTC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", createDate);

        // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
        // Create and execute the query.
        // Write the row count to the console window.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            for (int batches = 0; batches < numberOfBatches; batches++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            //connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    endTime = DateTime.Now;
    totalRowsInTable = GetWaveformRowCount();
    WritePerformance(batchSize, numberOfBatches, startTime, endTime, totalRowsInTable);
    Console.WriteLine(@"InsertWaveform - Batch Size: {0}  Number of Batches: {1}  Milliseconds: {2}  Total Rows: {3}", 
        batchSize, numberOfBatches, Math.Round((endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds, 0), totalRowsInTable);
}
```

SQL Server 2017 table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Waveform](
    [WaveformID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(-9223372036854775808,1) NOT NULL,
    [SampleCount] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TypeName] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [TypeID] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL,
    [Samples] [VARBINARY](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Compressed] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [TopicSessionID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [StartTimeUTC] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndTimeUTC] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Waveform_StartTimeUTC_WaveformID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StartTimeUTC] ASC,
    [WaveformID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The Gist for InsertWaveformsSS is https://gist.github.com/tgspacelabs/e3138479c16aff0bbd1e698ae7da7f3d

The Gist for SQLBulkCopyTest is https://gist.github.com/tgspacelabs/982230c6b810d06322451e116ba08c6f

Comment: Inserting a million 20k blobs row by agonizing row is going to take forever. You might also take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Not really sure what issue you are having with bulk load and concurrency though.

Comment: using a storedprocedure ?

Comment: You should use bulk insert in this scenario.

Comment: `I cannot use BULK LOAD APIs due to concurrency problems.` Could you `BULK INSERT` into a different table (e.g. `BulkInsertWaveform`) and then copy the data from that new table into `Waveform`? How many bytes (on average) is the blob payload?

Comment: The blob sizes average around 20K.  That is the number of data samples in one minute per device.  I am trying to maintain an ingest rate to accommodate at least 2000 devices at once, preferably more.  So the inserts have to be very fast and minimally blocking.

Comment: So 2000 inserts a second? A minute? An hour? _Did you try my suggestion? Did it work?_

Comment: @mjwills At least 2000 inserts per minute.  No, I did not try it because it will still block inserting into the Waveform table.  I previously tried a similar thing with a temporary table.

Comment: It will block **way less** since the insert into the main table is happening within the context of SQL Server itself (no network traffic involved). And there will be no blocking on `BulkInsertWaveform` if you create a separate upload table per upload (thus no possibility of blocking). _2000 inserts a minute is tiny, SQL Server can eat that up no worries._

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, 2000 inserts per SECOND not minute as previously stated.

Comment: What happened when you tried my suggestion? Did it help?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I can get about 8000 rows per second when inserting from table to table.  Now I just have to figure out how to get the rows into the upload table(s) as fast as possible.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052958/libraries-for-ado-net-to-rapidly-bulk-insert-data-into-a-database-from-a-csv-fi help? Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/single-bulk-copy-operations ?

Comment: I tried the SQLBulkCopy API's combined with table data copies.  It performed worse than just doing single inserts into the table.

1,000,000 rows as SQL inserts = 7.3 minutes.  BulkCopy to temporary table and copy to main table = 10.5 minutes.

Comment: Could you edit your post to add that code (i.e. leave your old code and add the new code also)? That is a surprising result.

Comment: @mjwills I've added 2 private Gists with the code for each program.

Comment: `SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(
                        "SELECT TOP (1000) 10000, 'My Old Type Name', 10751, [s].[Uncompressed], 0, 924847176, SYSUTCDATETIME(), DATEADD(SECOND, 60, SYSUTCDATETIME()) FROM [dbo].[Sample] AS [s];", sourceConnection);
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();` I would recommend you build the DataTable purely in RAM rather than querying it from the database. That is likely part of the perf issue with your bulk insert solution.

Comment: When you run the bulk solution, where is the 10.5 minutes being spent (e.g. 5 minutes generating the datatable, 4 minutes bulk inserting it, 1.5 minutes copying it into the final table)? Is the SQL Server running on the same machine as your local machine, or a different one?

Comment: @mjwills I adjusted the creation of the DataTable to be outside the loop.  The SQLBulkCopyTest execution time is down from 10.5 minutes to 4.3 minutes.  I am running the program on the same box with SQL Server to mitigate network lag.

Comment: Cool, so 4.3 minutes is a substantial speedup over 7.3 minutes. I would suggest **not** testing locally though, since the technique I suggested will likely handle network latency better than the multiple inserts solution. As an example, 4.3 minutes may become 10 minutes over the network, but 7.3 minutes might become 50 minutes. The problem with testing locally is that you will know which works better _locally_ only. How is the 4.3 minutes spent? How much time is bulk inserting? How much time copying into the final table?