# C# data table bulk update without looping

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to bulk update multiple columns in a c# Data table without looping ?

My data table has too many rows and looping and updating each rows takes a while to complete.

Comment: You could bulk insert into a temporal table and do a merge to the temp table into the final one.

Comment: Using Linq methods are much faster than conventional looping.  So enumerate through table like this :  dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray = new object[] {1,"A",5});

Comment: how many rows? and whats "a while"?

Comment: @mjwills Its just updates

Comment: @BugFinder Around 500- 1000 rows

Comment: thats tiny....  if its taking a long time it suggests somethings wrong with the db design

Comment: @BugFinder Its not in database. I updating a c# data table in the class file.

Comment: update the datasource not the table direct

Comment: Can you talk us through the nature of the updates? e.g. are you updating all the `Bob` column values to 4? Something else?

Answer (score -2):

You can create a new **DataType** in the database which can ***hold the whole table*** like DataTable do in c# or VB. And pass the whole table in one go to sp.

**Script to create new DataType**

CREATE TYPE EmpType AS TABLE 
(

ID INT, Name VARCHAR(3000),

Address VARCHAR(8000),

Operation SMALLINT

)

**Receive it in your sp and insert in your actual table**

ALTER PROCEDURE spEmpDetails

@Details EmpType READONLY

as

INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails(ID, Name, Address)

SELECT ID, Name, Address FROM @Details WHERE Operation=0;

**How you call that sp in your c# code**

`SqlCommand cmdProc = new SqlCommand("spEmpDetails", con);
cmdProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", dtDetails);
cmdProc.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` would be simpler and likely faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052958/libraries-for-ado-net-to-rapidly-bulk-insert-data-into-a-database-from-a-csv-fi